# No known instance method for selector objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an array which contains the following sample data

```
[{"MissionId":10,"Name":"Test 10！","Description":"Describe 10","MissionStatus":1,"ExpPoint":100,"CreatedDate":"2017-08-07T09:35:17.9882136Z","UserCount":0},{"MissionId":9,"Name":"Test 9！","Description":"Describe 9","MissionStatus":1,"ExpPoint":100,"CreatedDate":"2017-08-07T09:35:12.1392938Z","UserCount":0}]
```

I am able to print out the Description in console as below:-

```
po [self.missionArray[0]Description]
```

But when I tried to NSlog it, it says

```
No known instance method for selector 'Description'
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't just put the word `Description` there. You have to change it to `...array[0]["Description"]`. Look up how to deal with JSON or dictionaries.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth changed to self.missionArray[0]["Description"] but still doesnt work

Comment: How does it not work now?  Is there an error?  What do you see?  How is `self.missionArray` populated?

Comment: Please add the exact code for printing using `NSLog()`.

Comment: You're lying. `po [self.missionArray[0]Description]` would never work in the console. It is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "Description" with "description"

Description is not defined function in NSObject class . So You end up getting error -  "No known instance method for selector 'Description'"

description - is defined selector in NSObject. So it should work for You.

Comment: OP is not looking for the property `.description` of `NSObject` but for the value to the key `Description`. Read the first line of code in the question.